# SQL Where same as Join?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking a SQL code and I'm not sure what it does.
This is the code:

```
SELECT *   
FROM dba.spro_lotesfrutagranel,   
     dba.variedades,   
     dba.productores  
WHERE ( dba.variedades.espe_codigo = dba.spro_lotesfrutagranel.lote_espcod )     and  
     ( dba.variedades.vari_codigo = dba.spro_lotesfrutagranel.vari_codigo )
```

Does this the same as a left join? or not?

Thanks!

Comment: That is a simple INNER JOIN just written in old legacy style.

Comment: That is an obsolete notation. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Its more than just an INNER JOIN.. its an INNER JOIN between spro_lotesfrutagranel and variedades.. then that is CROSS JOINED to productores

Comment: This gives a good explanation of what gofr1 said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted! OP just wants to know what this code does! And good explanation needed, that is all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [old style join](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)! Use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspxhttp://)! You query should be rewriten like:

```
SELECT *   
FROM dba.spro_lotesfrutagranel sl
INNER JOIN dba.variedades v
ON v.espe_codigo = sl.lote_espcod and  
     v.vari_codigo = sp.vari_codigo
INNER JOIN dba.productores p
ON p.somecolumn = ...
```

As for now your query is a Cartesian join with some where statement, all rows from `spro_lotesfrutagranel` and `variedades` are connected by two columns both and then with ALL rows from `productores`.

Note: I add two links with some explanation.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm trying to understand a code writted by someone else...! I'm not using old style!!

Comment: It is just an advices! ;) with some explanation. Cartesian join with some where statement is similar to inner join.

Comment: I hope you got clarification you needed. I suggest you to rewrite this part of your query as mentioned in my answer, if you need all rows from third table use CROSS JOIN